# eJabberd copy of message sent

Tags: xml, chat, message, ejabberd

I'm trying to use eJabberd to host a chatting service. The problem I am running into is say we have a chat between UserA and UserB.
UserA sends the message "hello" to UserB.
Problem is, UserA doesn't receive a copy of that message he sent.

If eJabberd doesn't send back sent messages to the sender, then how am I supposed to keep multiple chat instances up to day?

For example, say I have two of my chat instances open with UserA.
Instance 1 sends the message "Hello" to UserB, but Instace2UserA has no idea that Instance2UserA sent a message, there for he can't have a log of that happening.

Am I maybe missing a setting, or something to make this work?

Thanks.

Another example is say you log onto facebook chat on your phone and on your computer, if you send someone a message from your phone, the chat on your computer knows it and shows it as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if you add the  tag to your message, it will send you a response back with the id of the message you sent.

Comment: Which tag do you need to add?

Comment: <delivered /> + <offline /> I believe was the tags. From what I gathered with both it will send back a message with the id of the message sent. I think adding the offline tag will allow <delivered> to be returned if it's stored offline. I may be completely wrong, but this was the best I was able to come up with.

Answer (score 2):

I think [XEP-0280 Message Carbons](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html) is what you're looking for. According to the XMPP site, the extension to the protocol is still in an experimental stage.

It does look like there is some interest in supporting this in ejabberd. See also:

http://mail.jabber.org/pipermail/standards/2011-March/024245.html
http://lists.jabber.ru/pipermail/ejabberd/2012-March/007413.html